# Juju - Can't deploy mysql/wordpress ; Invalid hardware information error

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu 14.04.02 server. I have juju installed on the same server(MaaS server). I have successfully bootstrap the MaaS environment and have juju-gui working. I have 1 node allocated to root ( the bootstrapped node) and 2 nodes on ready state. Now when I intended to deploy mysql+wordpress I have the following issue:

I did the following commands:

juju add-machine --constraints “mem=4G”
juju deploy --to 1 –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/mysql

and

juju add-machine --constraints “mem=4G”
juju deploy --to 2 –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/wordpress
[image]

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

I am going to share here my configuration, correct me if I have some mistakes here!

[image]

[image]

[image: One of the nodes in ready state;configuration]

[image]

[image: My juju-gui at the moment!]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work after bootstrap?

```
juju deploy --repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/mysql
juju deploy --repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/wordpress
```

There is no need to add-machine and then deploy.

You can also specify --constraints in the deploy command line if needed, but let's start simple.

Comment: I got the same thing at the first try http://i.imgur.com/LFNCwlb.png, after the second try I got this http://i.imgur.com/45rJh48.png

Comment: I suggest you start by filing a bug with MAAS then, because from now on it would just be some step by step debugging and this is not material for askubuntu.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+filebug